# Use IF in mysql select query to change the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, select

I need to create a select statement on a table like this:

```
id  rank name  city
34  0    adm   TO
44  0    sas   BA
44  1    wqe   BS
92  0    adm   TO
92  1    ter   BO
92  2    ter   BO
92  3    ter   RM
```

what I want to select is to count the number of rows where rank is > 0 but only for ids that have more than one rank value. For those id that just have one record, thus rank is 0, then I want to pick that record. If I use:

```
SELECT id, count(rank) as t 
FROM mytable 
WHERE rank > 0 
GROUP BY id
```

then, for instance, I omit `id=34`.

My optimal results set would be:

```
id  t
34  1
44  1
92  3
```

Any hint on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: So, what is the required output based on the sample data of your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following:

```
SELECT id,
       CASE 
          WHEN cntNonZero = 0 THEN cntZero           
          ELSE cntNonZero
       END AS t
FROM (
   SELECT id, 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN rank > 0 THEN 1 END) AS cntNonZero, 
          COUNT(CASE WHEN rank = 0 THEN 1 END) AS cntZero
   FROM mytable 
   GROUP BY id ) s
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0e311/7)

Comment: any idea how to add a count(city) to this query?